# No se adjunta fichero al enviar mail en Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Hola Tengo un formulario donde se adjunta un pdf. El resto de campos los recibo y se añaden correctamente en el mail.
Después de enviar el formualario llega todo correctamente pero no me adjunta el PDF.
Este es mi código. Utilizo $files = $this->request->getFile('file'); pero llega vacio.

Según la documentacion creo que esta correcto

........
Simplest usage
With the simplest usage, a single file might be submitted like:

Which would return a simple file instance like:

$file = $this->request->getFile('userfile');

```
    <form class="contact-form" id="contact-form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('public/TrabajaConNosotros/sendMail') ?>">
                        <div class="row my-form">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                                <div id="result"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.nombre'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="candidate_fname" name="firstName" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.nombre'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.apellidos'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="candidate_lname" name="lastName" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.apellidos'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.email'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="userEmail" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.email'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.telefono'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_subject" name="userTelefono" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.telefono'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.nacimiento'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="user_subject" name="userFecha" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.nacimiento'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.direccion'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_email" name="userDireccion" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.direccion'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.ciudad'); ?>:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_subject" name="userCiudad" placeholder="<?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.ciudad'); ?>" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.info'); ?>:</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="user_message" name="userMessage" placeholder="" rows="7" required="required"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">

                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <label><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.doc'); ?>:</label>
                            <p>
                                <small><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.files'); ?></small>
                            </p>
                            <input type="file"  id="file" name="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf">

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-12">

                                    <input type="checkbox" required name="terms"><?php echo lang('Translate.trabaja_con_nosotros.form.privacidad'); ?>
                                <br>
                                <button class="btn web-btn user-contact rounded-pill contact_btn" type="submit"><?php echo lang('Translate.boton.enviar'); ?>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

public function sendMail(){

        
        $to = 'email@email.com';
        $nombre = $this->request->getVar('firstName');
        $apellidos = $this->request->getVar('lastName');
        $email = $this->request->getVar('userEmail');
        $telefono = $this->request->getVar('userTelefono');
        $fecha = $this->request->getVar('userFecha');
        $direccion = $this->request->getVar('userDireccion');
        $ciudad = $this->request->getVar('userCiudad');
        $message = $this->request->getVar('userMessage');
        $files = $this->request->getFile('file');

        $mensaje = 'Nombre:' . $nombre . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Apellidos:' . $apellidos . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Email:' . $email . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Teléfono:' . $telefono . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Fecha Nacimiento:' . $fecha . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Dirección:' . $direccion . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Ciudad:' . $ciudad . '<br>';
        $mensaje .= 'Mensaje:' . $message . '<br>';



        $email = \Config\Services::email();
        $session = \Config\Services::session();
        $subject = 'Formulario Trabaja con nosotros';
        $email->setTo($to);
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        $email->setFrom('email@email.com');
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        $email->setMessage($mensaje);
        $email->attach($files);


        //Send mail
        if($email->send()){

            $session->setFlashdata("email_sent","Gracias. Hemos recibido tu mensaje.");

            return redirect()->to(base_url('/TrabajaConNosotros'));

        }else{
            $session->set_flashdata("email_sent","Ha habido un error al enviar el correo.");

            print_r($email->printDebugger(['headers']));
            //$email->load->view('email_form');
        }

    }
```

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser el problema de que no se adjunte el PDF?
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trabaja con archivos se necesita agregar la propiedad `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para permitir el envío de archivos a través de un formulario.

Por lo cual el form debe quedar así

```
<form class="contact-form" id="contact-form-data" action="<?php echo base_url('public/TrabajaConNosotros/sendMail') ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Posiblemente después de obtener el archivo necesites guardarlo en disco para enviarlo

```
if ($files->isValid() && ! $files->hasMoved())
   {
           $newName = $files->getName();
           $files->move(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
   }
```

Y para el envío sería

```
$email->attach(WRITEPATH.'uploads', $newName);
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta.
He probado lo que me comentabas y al añadir la propiedad enctype="multipart/form-data" veo que si llega. Pero al añadir las siguientes lineas que comentas sigue sin enviarse. He hecho un dump() de $files y me sale esto

Comment: object(CodeIgniter\HTTP\Files\UploadedFile)#68 (9) { ["path":protected]=> string(0) "" ["originalName":protected]=> string(11) "pruebas.pdf" ["name":protected]=> string(11) "pruebas.pdf" ["originalMimeType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["error":protected]=> int(6) ["hasMoved":protected]=> bool(false) ["size":protected]=> int(0) ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(0) "" ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=> string(0) "" }

¿Alguna idea? Muchas gracias!